Django Remove DB (Python manage migrate)
I'm using Django.
After running python manage migrate, the DB is created normally. However, after some time, the DB suddenly disappears. The drop command does not exist in my code.
I am curious as to why the DB is deleted. All data removed. (DB, Collection, Field)
Does anyone know the cause?
This is my code
below code is app/models
model
from djongo import models

class RealTime(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    site = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()
    create_time = models.DateTimeField()
    GPTAnswer = models.TextField()
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'realtimebest'

class Daily(models.Model):
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()
    create_time = models.DateTimeField()

Below code is Schema:
schema
import graphene
from graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType
from graphene import Mutation

from .views import board_summary
from .communityWebsite.models import RealTime, Daily

class RealTimeType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = RealTime

class DailyType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Daily

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_realtime = graphene.List(RealTimeType)
    all_daily = graphene.List(DailyType)

    def resolve_all_realtime(self, info, **kwargs):
        return RealTime.objects.all()

    def resolve_all_daily(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Daily.objects.all()

class SummaryBoardMutation(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        board_id = graphene.String(required=True)

    response = graphene.String()

    def mutate(self, info, board_id):
        response = board_summary(board_id)
        return SummaryBoardMutation(response=response)

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    summary_board = SummaryBoardMutation.Field()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)

settings.py
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     "corsheaders",

    # Graph QL
    'graphene_django',
    'graphene_mongo',
    
    'webCrwaling',
    'kingwangjjang',
    'chatGPT'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'kingwangjjang.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # 'DIRS': [],
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kingwangjjang.wsgi.application'

# Database
# MongoDB settings
DB_URI = 'mongodb://'+ DB_HOST + '/' + DB_USER + ':' + DB_PASSWORD
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': True,
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': DB_URI
        }  
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ko-kr'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# GRAPHENE = {
#     "SCHEMA": "webCrwaling.schema.schema"
# }

Insert Data
def get_real_time_best(self):
    req = requests.get('https://www.dcinside.com/', headers=self.g_headers[0])
    html_content = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    li_elements = soup.select('#dcbest_list_date li')
    already_exists_post = []

    for li in li_elements:
        p_element = li.select_one('.box.besttxt p')
        a_element = li.select_one('.main_log')
        time_element = li.select_one('.box.best_info .time')

        if p_element and a_element and time_element:
            p_text = p_element.get_text(strip=True)
            a_href = a_element['href']
            no_value = a_href.split('no=')[-1]
            time_text = time_element.get_text(strip=True)

            if(time_text.find('-') > 0): 
                break  # 오늘 것만 추가 (이전 글은 제외 (DB에서 확인))

            # 시간 13:40 -> 2024.01.29 13:40 로 수정
            now = datetime.now()
            hour, minute = map(int, time_text.split(':'))
            # 시간 설정 및 datetime 객체 생성
            target_datetime = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour, minute)

            try:
                existing_instance = RealTime.objects.filter(_id=no_value).first()
                if existing_instance:
                    already_exists_post.append(no_value)
                    continue
                else:
                    RealTime.objects.get_or_create(
                        _id=no_value,
                        defaults={
                            'site' : 'dcinside',
                            'title': p_text,
                            'url': a_href,
                            'create_time': target_datetime,
                            'GPTAnswer': DEFAILT_GPT_ANSWER
                        }
                    )
            except IntegrityError:
                continue

    print("already exists post", already_exists_post)

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
Could this be a problem?
What part needs to be modified to solve the problem of data completely disappearing?

Time Zone = False

But Python manage migrate is normal

What do you mean with "the problem of data completely disappearing"?

Everytime you change model fields you also need to change database schema - running python manage.py makemigrations prepares recipe for these changes, while python manage.py migrate applies this recipe to the database.

The database was dropped..

I always do it that way.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

No, python manage.py migrate will not drop your database.

It's edited
"I am curious as to why the DB is deleted. All data removed. (DB, Collection, Field)"

HI, can you please paste the error, that ll give the better idea about what you are talking about

I don't know..
When DB was deleted

No error messages. I don't think there's even a specific time. Maybe it's a situation I'm not familiar with.

The migrate command does not delete / drop your database unless you have some migration that does that. It's not really clear what you are asking here. Please clarify exactly what the problem is.

Corrected the post. Sorry for the confusion in the content.

It might be better if you read the documentation on migrations and understood that before editing your question. As currently asked we have no idea what the problem is.

What the DB log says? That would be the initial point to investigate!

I added an authentication process to mongodb which solved the problem of db disappearing. Checking the log as suggested in the comments let me to this solution.
